# Trouble getting search results in english

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to perform a google search and fetch the result. It is working fine at this moment. However, the only problem I'm facing is that I get most of the results in my native language which is not english whereas i get the result in english when I perform the same search in google chrome browser.

How can i modify my script to get all the search results in english?

This is my try so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "http://www.google.com/search?q={}"

def fetch_results(query):
    res = requests.get(link.format(query.replace(" ","+")))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("span"):
        print(item.get_text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_results('india')
```

Comment: Beware that Google will quickly catch up on you and _ban_ your IP address (i.e. your crawler will soon start getting captcha requests). If you want to use their search engine to provide your app with data, you'll have to pay them to use their [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) for anything more than 100 queries a day.

Comment: Thanks @zwer for your suggestion. I will bear that in mind. The thing is I'm not worried about what google does to my crawler. I just needed to know if there is any option available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a language filter by using the url `https://www.google.com/search?q={}&hl={}` and setting `hl` to `en` for English.

The various options are described in the google search api docs (this link is for xml, but many are available as query params as well): https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#wsQueryTerms